Open a cmd window and init script from git bash on windows
I haven't been able to figure out how to open a cmd window from inside git bash with the following conditions:

Target Type = Application
Target Loaction = system32
Target =
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k
""C:\Users\thebi.espressif\idf_cmd_init.bat"
esp-idf-f4096c5fb8232f5ffa980cf1b514d882"
Start in location specified.

Here's how this usually works. You browse to the folder and double click this, and it opens the cmd window in the starts in folder. Then it runs the idf_cmd_init.bat script. That does loads of useful things for you like set up local environment variables for the version of esp-idf specified in the input argument.
Where I am getting stuck is that I'd like to bundle some of this into a shell script. Basically, I'd like to open this cmd window, run idf.py build and then close it again. However, whichever way I try, I can't seem to make it work.
My code:
# Define the path to the shortcut target command
esp_idf_v5_1_init='C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\idf_cmd_init.bat esp-idf-f4096c5fb8232f5ffa980cf1b514d882'

# Run the shortcut target command using cmd.exe
cmd.exe /k "$esp_idf_v5_1_init" && (
    # Run additional commands in the resulting cmd window
    cmd.exe /k "cd %ESP32_REPO_PROD% && esp-idf.py build"
)

What happens is that the cmd window opens and does nothing. I've tried as many variations as I can think of: powershell, /c, /k, echo-ing the cmd stuff to a separate file. But I can't figure it out.
It would be nice to be able to remove the manual steps.
Update
I tried the suggestion from @Phillipe.
What I see is this:
$ ./test.sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4291]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\...\temp>call C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\idf_cmd_init.bat esp-idf-f4096c5fb8232f5ffa980cf1b514d882
Setting PYTHONNOUSERSITE, was not set
Using Python in C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\python_env\idf5.1_py3.11_env\Scripts\
Python 3.11.2
Using Git in C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\idf-git\2.39.2\cmd\
git version 2.39.2.windows.1
This .bat file is for Windows CMD.EXE shell only.

What you normally see when the ESP-IDF CMD opens is this:
Setting PYTHONNOUSERSITE, was not set
Using Python in C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\python_env\idf5.1_py3.11_env\Scripts\
Python 3.11.2
Using Git in C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\idf-git\2.39.2\cmd\
git version 2.39.2.windows.1
Checking Python compatibility
Setting IDF_PATH: C:\Espressif\v5.1.2

Adding ESP-IDF tools to PATH...
Not using an unsupported version of tool cmake found in PATH: 3.22.1.
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp-elf-gdb\12.1_20221002\xtensa-esp-elf-gdb\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\riscv32-esp-elf-gdb\12.1_20221002\riscv32-esp-elf-gdb\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-12.2.0_20230208\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32s2-elf\esp-12.2.0_20230208\xtensa-esp32s2-elf\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32s3-elf\esp-12.2.0_20230208\xtensa-esp32s3-elf\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\riscv32-esp-elf\esp-12.2.0_20230208\riscv32-esp-elf\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\esp32ulp-elf\2.35_20220830\esp32ulp-elf\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\cmake\3.24.0\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\openocd-esp32\v0.12.0-esp32-20230921\openocd-esp32\bin
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\ninja\1.10.2\
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\idf-exe\1.0.3\
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\ccache\4.8\ccache-4.8-windows-x86_64
    C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\tools\dfu-util\0.11\dfu-util-0.11-win64
    C:\Espressif\v5.1.2\tools

Checking if Python packages are up to date...
Constraint file: C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\espidf.constraints.v5.1.txt
Requirement files:
 - C:\Espressif\v5.1.2\tools\requirements\requirements.core.txt
Python being checked: C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\python_env\idf5.1_py3.11_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python requirements are satisfied.

Detected installed tools that are not currently used by active ESP-IDF version.
For removing old versions of ccache, cmake, dfu-util, esp-rom-elfs, esp32s2ulp-elf, esp32ulp-elf, idf-driver, idf-eclipse, idf-exe, openocd-esp32, riscv32-esp-elf, riscv32-esp-elf-gdb, xtensa-esp-elf-gdb, xtensa-esp32-elf, xtensa-esp32s2-elf, xtensa-esp32s3-elf use command 'python.exe C:\Espressif\v5.1.2\tools\idf_tools.py uninstall'
For free up even more space, remove installation packages of those tools. Use option 'python.exe C:\Espressif\v5.1.2\tools\idf_tools.py uninstall --remove-archives'.


Done! You can now compile ESP-IDF projects.
Go to the project directory and run:

  idf.py build


D:\....\...>

Poking around in the idf_cmd_init.bat file, it appears to get as far as the last line successfully:
:: Check if this is a recent enough copy of ESP-IDF.
:: If so, use export.bat provided there.
:: Note: no "call", will not return into this batch file.
if exist "%IDF_PATH%\export.bat" %IDF_PATH%\export.bat

This seems to be the .bat file which "is for Windows CMD.EXE shell only".
Writing scripts and using the shell hurts my brain.

I don't know what the batch file is doing (did you try to put a @echo on into it?), but your 2nd cmd looks flakey. You haven't done a export ESP32_REPO_PROD=.... anywhere.

@user1934428 Never gets to that line anyway. ESP32_REPO_PROD is just a standard environment variabel for the machine. I can echo that no problem from anywhere.

So, does it at least start the batchfile? Or does it execute it, but never returns? Your question is IMO pretty unclear, and you don't show what you did for debugging.

@user1934428 I've added detail. Could you remove the close request. I want to figure this out.

Well, first of all, it seems to be mainly a problem with the batch script idf_cmd_init.bat, so I would remove the bash tag from your question. As you see from the code you have posted, if export.bat exists, this batch file is executed, and the control is not returned to the caller. This is a Windows-"feature".  I'm not a Windows expert, but from this I would conclude that idf_cmd_init.bat also does not return to your master bash script anymore, which corresponds to your observations. Can't you throw away the bat scripts and rewrite everything in bash?

Try this :
#!/bin/bash

esp_idf_v5_1_init='call C:\Users\thebi\.espressif\idf_cmd_init.bat esp-idf-f4096c5fb8232f5ffa980cf1b514d882'
cmd.exe << EOF
$esp_idf_v5_1_init
cd %ESP32_REPO_PROD%
python esp-idf.py build
EOF


Not quite I'm afraid. I've added an update to show what this does.

The main idea is to use cmd.exe << EOF. Does that work ?

I'm not 100% sure. It runs everything inside the bash window. Is the expectation for it to spawn a new process and hence completely new cmd window? It is not doing that.
